# Permission denied when trying to mount USB storage

Tags: rooting, shell, beaglebone-black

I'm trying to mount USB storage using the "Terminal Emulator" app with the following commands:

`mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sd* /storage/usb1`

or

`su mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sd* /storage/usb1`

But I get a `permission denied` message.

I've tried different su binaries. One of them is:  http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/android/f/509/t/279726.aspx

The shell command which I'm using is working in adb, but I have to execute it within an app. Without permissions, I cannot do that.

So:

1. Is it possible to root this Android image (I'm using TI release for Beaglebone Black)?
2. OR, can I give permissions using chmod? If I can, which files should I give permission?
3. OR, is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Yes ADB of Beaglebone is rooted but there isn't a SU binary. So I wasn't able to execute this code within my app:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sd* /storage/usb1");
```

But I finally find a program to root Beaglebone Black and install a valid SU binary. You can download it here :

http://www.unlockroot.com/unlockroot.html

**But be careful! It installs bunch of unwanted programs to your computer too.** Once you install the program, connect your Beaglebone via USB. First you need to unroot Beaglebone. So open the program, you downloaded, and click UNROOT. It will take a couple of minutes. Then restart your Beaglebone and click ROOT from program. Then restart your Beaglebone again. And voila :D You have 100% rooted Beaglebone with a valid SU binary.

You can mount and unmount USB storages and copy files within your application . But You should do it like that :

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();

os.write(("mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sd* /storage/usb1;
           cp -R /myFile /storage/usb1").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: That site seems really, really sketchy - In your situation, it would probably be a better idea to try to install SuperSu or Superuser and see if one of those su binaries would work.